# Setting authorization header in http client in ionic and angular 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am learning ionic for mobile development latest version. I used http client for calling REST API. But I am facing some issues -

1) I am using POST but it showing me as option.

2) How to set authorization header . I am using bearer token and my rest API is written in PHP.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: ^ without code.. we are just playing a guessing game

Answer (score 0):

Use **HttpHeaders** to set your token. token can be defined in a string

```
func() {    
var headers = new HttpHeaders();
let body = new HttpParams();
body = body.set('key','value');
headers = headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
return this.http.post('post-url.com', body,{
headers:headers
});
}
```

Hope that helps!